# 2 full bridge with 2 secondary winding in series... is it possible?

Tags: power, ac, dc, transformer

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPG8KA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Is this possible? Think of the center tap transformer as a 2 winding connected in series

Answer (score 4):

This is OK, it's not a problem what you've done but note that the two individual bridge outputs are not isolated and this means they can't be connected together (N1 to N2) without the voltage levels changing. If you want a +V, 0V and -V supply use this: -

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTQBmR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. Well I was going to use a center tap but I am trying to make a linear power supply my self. I was thinking I could use 2 secondary winding and have 2 supplies and also connect them in series and have a dual rail when I need it. Also why can't I connect N1 and N2 they are at the same potential right?

Comment: @Mastaan - if the lower winding is providing the most positive voltage in the "system" - it will drive current thru BR2 and if N2 is connected to N1 it will carry on driving that current through BR1 (lower left diode) and "find" the nice negative voltage on the top of the secondary winding - it will short out the windings on half cycles and turn to smoke. Using two seperate windings is fine